I killed a task called 'gnome-session-a' without wanting to and my ubuntu broke up
I am new into the Linux world, so i was trying to access an App Task List Management Tool by the terminal to kill the task of an specific app that bugged,  i saw some tutorials in Ubuntu's forums to learn how to access it on the terminal, but the task i was hoping it was the correct one to kill, was an "gnome-session-a", and when i pressed enter my Ubuntu broke up. So please, How can i fix this because it bugged the entire front end of my Ubuntu?

What happened after you rebooted?

my extensions disappeared and my dock was kind weird, but now 90% of the problem i fixed, but my "show apps" button isnt there anymore :)

and the commom commands doenst work too

If you logout & login again; your GUI processes I'd expect to return to normal. I suspect your process wasn't gnome-session-a but that was only the first part of the name (full name too long for your onscreen tool to show), so I'm not sure what you actually killed.
